# Do not allow numbers but allow character with "&"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an input field below like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"/>
```

But it still allows "&" inputs

What i have tried

```
var regexp = /[A-Z0-9!@#$%^*_|w+]/g;
if($(this).val().match(regexp)){
$(this).val( $(this).val().replace(regexp,'') );
```

I want names to be input and want to display an error message when the string contains a "&", How can I achieve this?

Comment: `[A-Z0-9!@#$%^*_|w+]` ... matches A-Z, 0-9, and any of these characters `!@#$%^*_|w+` - is that what you expect? why do you match lower case w but only upper case A-Z?

Comment: `But it still allows "&" inputs` - of course ... it's not one of `[A-Z0-9!@#$%^*_|w+]`

Comment: Those should be allowed but i tried this "&", if i included like this "!&@#$%^*_|w+" not working, am i wrong?

Comment: if you add `&` to the regexp, then it won't be allowed in the input ... at the moment you don't allow `A-Z`, `w`, `0-9` and any of `! @ # $ % ^ * _ | +` - anything else is fine, so `a-v`, `x-z`, `& ( ) - = : ;` etc etc should be OK

Comment: @JaromandaX thank your support..

Comment: Really? I think there's serious issues with what you think your RegExp does compared with what you want it to do

Comment: @JaromandaX, This is this, i converted input field as password, when i type "&" it is not typing, i checked my wireless keyboard. which has some issue. anyway your support i really appreciated.

Comment: @prasanga could you please mention your actual requirement.. u want to get rid of '&' entry from your current regex or you need a good name validation regex which wont allows any special characters ?

Comment: The title says you want to allow `&`, but the question says you want to display an error message. Which is it really?

Comment: what i want to allow these special characters ! @ # $ % ^ * _ | +  &